# Is there any performance drawback in using functions inside StyleSheet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styles

To simplify code and pass props to my styles I came up with this sollution

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  someNormalStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  dynamicStyle(color) {
   return {
    backgroundColor: color
   }
  }
})
```

which I would then use normally in my components i.e.

```
<View style={style.someNormalStyle} />
<View style={style.dynamicStyle('blue')} />
```

This seems to work, I just wanted to verify if there is any performance hit from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually [race the horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/amp/) ?

If you do, you'll probably notice that *one function call* won't cost you that much, and the engine might even inline it.

"To simplify code" ... yup, thats the point here.